# Get orientation of an image with respect to base image using Surf and Perspective Transform

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, image-processing

In module del5.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

base_img = cv2.imread("/tmp/a/1.jpg")
test_img = cv2.imread("/tmp/a/1_1.jpg")

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()

base_keyPoints,base_descriptors=surf.detectAndCompute(base_img,None)
test_keyPoints,test_descriptors=surf.detectAndCompute(test_img,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

matches = bf.knnMatch(base_descriptors, test_descriptors,k=2)#, k=2)

goodMatches = []

for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
        goodMatches.append(m)

print len(goodMatches)

sourcePoints=np.float32([base_keyPoints[m.queryIdx].pt for m in goodMatches])
destinationPoints=np.float32([test_keyPoints[m.trainIdx].pt for m in goodMatches ])

print len(sourcePoints)
print len(destinationPoints)

sourcePoints = np.float32([[c[0],c[1] ]for c in sourcePoints])
destinationPoints = np.float32([[c[0],c[1] ]for c in destinationPoints])

_m = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(sourcePoints, destinationPoints)
```

I am using python 2.7 and OpenCV 3. I have to same images but test image is 90 degrees rotated with respect to base image

In above code, i try to get a perfect view of the test(rotated image) like the base image and my algos steps are:

1. read both images (base and test)
2. create surf
3. get features of both image
4. extract good features
5. get feature point of both images(source point and destination point)
6. get perspective transform and perform warp perspective on image to get perfect view

but when try to get the perspective view I get the error

**Output:**

```
> 4116
> 4116 
> 4116 
> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.checkVector(2,
> CV_32F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4) in
> getPerspectiveTransform, file
> /opt/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 7135 Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "del5.py", line 41, in <module>
>     _m = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(sourcePoints, destinationPoints) cv2.error: /opt/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:7135: error:
> (-215) src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_32F)
> == 4 in function getPerspectiveTransform
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you getPerspectiveTransform Function you need to pass only Four points.
And you are trying to pass a list.

```
//In your code change this line to this.
_m = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(sourcePoints, destinationPoints)

//Change into this one.
_m = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(sourcePoints[0:4], destinationPoints[0:4])
```

For perspective transformation, you need a 3x3 transformation matrix. Straight lines will remain straight even after the transformation. To find this transformation matrix, you need 4 points on the input image and corresponding points on the output image. Among these 4 points, 3 of them should not be collinear. The transformation matrix can be found by the function cv2.getPerspectiveTransform. Then apply cv2.warpPerspective with this 3x3 transformation matrix.

As per the OpenCV Documentation [Perspective Transformation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html)

Comment: To add to this answer, `findHomography()` will find the best homography based on >=4 points using RANSAC to filter matches. So instead of just using four points....use all of them!